# Nodejs pm2 is always restarting when I reboot Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have an express nodejs server running in Ubuntu LTS with pm2. The server runs fine, but when I restart Ubuntu, the server is always rebooting.

I use an ecossystem.config like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'gTimeTracking',
    script: 'index.js',
    args: 'one two',
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```

I started the server with this command:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

And with `pm2 save`

and I have this infinite error on Ubuntu reboot

```
0|gTimeTracking  | Server running since: Mon Jul 01 2019 09:36:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)
PM2              | Change detected on path logs/logger-01-07-2019-09.log for app gTimeTracking - restarting
PM2              | Stopping app:gTimeTracking id:0
PM2              | App [gTimeTracking:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2              | pid=16255 msg=process killed
PM2              | App [gTimeTracking:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2              | App [gTimeTracking:0] online
0|gTimeTracking  | Server running since: Mon Jul 01 2019 09:36:44 GMT+0200 (CEST)
PM2              | Change detected on path logs/logger-01-07-2019-09.log for app gTimeTracking - restarting
PM2              | Stopping app:gTimeTracking id:0
PM2              | App [gTimeTracking:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2              | pid=16274 msg=process killed
PM2              | App [gTimeTracking:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2              | App [gTimeTracking:0] online
```

Last time I had this problem I had to reinstall many times pm2 to relaunch the server, but now this method doesn't works and isn't an stable solution

What could be wrong?

Comment: How do you expect server to keep running when you reboot the system?
and regarding infinite errors, pm2 keeps trying to restart the node process, check if your code runs with `node index.js`

Comment: Hi, the infinite error is that it's rebooting always, with node index, js it works perfect, and with supervisor index.js, but I need to controll my server with pm2 in this case. There are no errors without pm2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `pm2 cleardump` for solve the problem with `pm2 delete all` and `pm2 kill` it didn't works for me. (I didn't have to change anything about the loggers path)